# How can I add custom date range in CiviCRM date picker?

Tags: search, custom-search, date-range, datepicker

The standard *Choose Date Range* date picker allows to select from multiple presets, including Last 7 days, Last 30 days, Last 60 days.

Is there a way to configure my own preset (in this case **last 35 days**)?

Which file should I edit or is there an article on this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your own relative filters using existing ones

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Option Groups.

Look for Relative Date Filters >> Edit Options

Click on Add option, Give a name and set value as ending_35.day

[image]

Comment: See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/relative-date-formats/

Comment: Epic. Did not know it is in UI.